# Properly using Python from the command line

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to use Python on Windows which, from what I've seen, is actually not the norm. I'm really just trying to get a script I downloaded to function, but it has all these dependencies. I've gone through the process of trying to install them, but I seem to be failing in one fundamental way. When I read Python tutorials, Python can simply be invoked through the command line. I've modified my PATH to include Python's directory, but this seems to change nothing. Additionally, every Pip tutorial I've read says you can just use 'pip install whatever' as soon as you install it, but I also lack this capability.

Comment: Restarted the cmd prompt? What is it exactly that fails (give us some output). Regarding `pip` you need to include the pip `PATH` into your windows `PATH` variable. i run all my python scripts with: `C:\>python myscript.py` and it works like a swizz clockwork.

Comment: you type 'python' and you get `'python' is not recognized...`? How did you set PATH? Does `echo %PATH%` show the path?

Comment: Also note that for Python 3.3 there's a launcher for Windows which adds itslef to PATH automatically and also can run different installed versions of Python. See http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-397-python-launcher-for-windows.

Comment: The launcher worked. Thanks for the help!

Uh, actually, now there's a new problem. When I try to use pip, it runs, but then crashes and says there's no module named pip...

Comment: It may be "not the norm" in that the majority of the core developers are on Mac or Linux… but I don't think it's very rare among Python _users_ to be on Windows. They wouldn't have put more time into the Windows binary installer (and into making it easy to build binary module installers, etc.) if nobody were using it…